# How to track share and like count of photo that i have share through android app on facebook and twitter?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I have made an android app that helps user to snap photo and share to social media like facebook and twitter . How to i count share and likes of those photo shared through my app

Here is my share to facebook code .

```
public class shareToFb extends  AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return getBitmapFromUrl(params[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ImageOverlay.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sharing to fb");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap overlayBitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(overlayBitmap);

        progressDialog.hide();


        bitmapProfilePicture = bitmapProfilePicture.createScaledBitmap(
                bitmapProfilePicture, overlayBitmap.getWidth(),
                overlayBitmap.getHeight(), true);
        final Bitmap bitmap = overlay(bitmapProfilePicture,
                overlayBitmap);

        String f = saveBitmap(bitmap);
         callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        final ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(ImageOverlay.this);
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)){
            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(bitmap)
                    .build();


            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();


            shareDialog.show(content);

        }

    }

}
```

Here is my share to twitter code :

```
        String f = saveBitmap(bitmap);

        TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(ImageOverlay.this)
                .image(Uri.fromFile(new File(f)));
        builder.show();
```

Comment: Use share preference

Comment: Jinal Patel can you elaborate it plz.

Comment: you can save int value of photo share in preference on successfully share,

Comment: I am beginner  on this issue can you help me how to do it ?